# Optimized way to get non matching records

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone suggest the fastest way to retrieve NON matching records from two tables?

Preferably without a SUBQUERY

Thanks,

Prabhu.

Comment: Show us your query and tell us what is wrong with your idea.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you wish to solve.

Comment: You'll also need to post: indexes, cardinality of columns, size of tables, explain plans, an explanation of what you're actually trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA A
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableB B WHERE A.Match = B.Match)
```

Comment: Could you explain the statement?

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to use an `OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM TABLE_A a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B b
    WHERE b.KEY_VALUE = a.KEY_VALUE
  WHERE b.PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE IS NULL;
```

Whether this will prove faster than the use of a subquery and NOT EXISTS clause would depend on the data in question and would require benchmarking to be proven or disproven.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: The cost of the subqery and the above query is same and also the exec time. Any improvement ?

Comment: Are there indexes on the fields involved? In the above example indexes would probably be helpful on TABLE_A.KEY_VALUE, TABLE_B.KEY_VALUE, and TABLE_B.PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE. Best of luck.

Comment: Yes there are indexes !